# emit bradcast message in callback with flask socketIO

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

I have trouble using Flask socketio. Here is the code I use:

```
import json
import time

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from engineio.async_drivers import gevent
from flask_cors import CORS

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

import queue
queue_notification_thread = queue.Queue()

def callback_notification(data):
    print("callback device {}".format(data))
    notification_thread = threading.Thread(target=notification_job, args=(data))
    notification_thread.start()
    queue_notification_thread.put(notification_thread)


def notification_job(data):
    print("callback device in notification job {}".format(data))
    socketio.emit("notification", data, broadcast=True)


@socketio.on('request')
def handle_message(data):
    Logger.instance().debug('received message: {}'.format(data))
    try:
        if data.__contains__('data'):
            response_message = dict()
            response_message['Devices'] = dict()
            response_message['Devices']['event'] = 'MY_EVENT'
            socketio.emit('notification', response_message, broadcast=True)

        else:
            Logger.instance().error('Can\'t parse data {}'.format(data))
    except OSError as err:
        print('Error: when process {} \n ValueError {}'.format(data, err))



@socketio.on_error_default  # handles all namespaces without an explicit error handler
def default_error_handler(e):
    print('An error occured:')
    print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    serialReader = SerialReader()
    serialReader.start_reading(callback_notification)

    http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

And the reader with call asynchronisly:

```
class SerialController:
    serial_port: str
    serial_device: serial.Serial
    reading_thread: threading.Thread
    device_name: str

    def __init__(self, serial_port: str = "/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=115200, read_timeout=0.2, device_name=''):
        self.serial_port = serial_port
        self.device_name = device_name
        self.serial_device = serial.Serial(port=self.serial_port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=0.2)

    def start_reading(self, callback_function):
        self.reading_callback = callback_function
        # run the thread to
        self.reading_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.read_job)
        self.reading_thread.start()

    def read_job(self):
        available_data = 0
        while True:
            if self.serial_device.in_waiting > available_data:
                available_data = self.serial_device.in_waiting
                print('available_data {}'.format(available_data))
                time.sleep(0.1)
            else:
                if available_data != 0:
                    data = self.serial_device.readall()
                    available_data = 0
                    if data != b'' and data != b'\n':
                        if self.reading_callback != None:
                            message = dict()
                            message["Reader"] = dict()
                            message["Reader"]["device"] = self.device_name
                            message["Reader"]["data"] = data
                            self.reading_callback(message)
                time.sleep(1)
```

When I receive a message in  @socketio.on('request') the bradcast emission work properly with no delay.  When I use callback_notification called from my serial reader the breadcast emission have variable delay ( from 1seconde to 10 secondes).

On my server the message "callback device ..." is printed instantly  but the client receive the message after few second.

I tried to the emission call in a thread like in the shown code but there is no improvment

Comment: Are you using an async framework, such as eventlet or gevent? If you are, then my guess is that your serial code is incompatible with it and causes blocking.

Comment: Indeed I use gevent. How should I design m'y serial code?

Comment: If you use an async framework you have to use compatible libraries. In general hardware code is incompatible. I'd say try dropping gevent, that is probably the easiest path.

Comment: What do you mean by dropping gevent? What should I use?

Comment: If you are using Gunicorn, one option is to use the simple-websocket package, which is compatible with the "threading" async mode of Flask-SocketIO. Docs: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#gunicorn-web-server